# List all directories in a folder and pass those each to another script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am working on a deduplication script and decided it would be easier to hand it a parent directory and let it work on each child folder, rather than doing each folder separately.  I was assuming this was going to be simple, but I can't seem to get this to work properly.  This is roughly what I have now:

```
SET base_folder=%1

for /d %%d in ("%1\*") do (
    set current_dir=%%d
    -- here is where I want to call my script with current_dir as the %1 --
)
```

Comment: there's no `for /d` in DOS. Don't call "DOS" for things you run in cmd.exe, [they're very different](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're don't appear to be using `base_folder`, so there's no need to set it.

You don't need to set `current_dir`; just use `%%d` directly. If the script you want to use to process each directory is also a batch file, you'll need to `CALL` it:

```
for /d %%d in ("%1\*") do (
    CALL myotherscript "%%d"
)
```

See [SS64 on `CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html).

Comment: This works, but for each branch in the tree it is calling the script rather than using the entire path at once.  For example if the directory is "E:\Photos - Backup\Capture One Sessions\COMPETITION" it is calling the script 5 times with only pieces of the path.

Comment: My error on that - edited... I have a tendency to forget about files/folder with spaces in them, because I tend not to use spaces in filenames out of long habit dating back well before Windows.

Comment: Even with the quotes, I am still getting the same behavior.  This is the log from my deduplication script showing what was passed in.

`
'
Mon 06/13/2022  7:40:01.00 - SEARCHING E:\Photos\Capture 
END SEARCH 
. 
Mon 06/13/2022  7:40:02.85 - SEARCHING -\Capture 
END SEARCH 
. 
Mon 06/13/2022  7:40:03.27 - SEARCHING Backup\Capture\Capture 
END SEARCH 
. 
Mon 06/13/2022  7:40:03.56 - SEARCHING One\Capture 
END SEARCH 
.`

Comment: This may be a problem with your called script.